# What is the scope of Orleans grains that are created on the client with the key Guid.Empty?

Tags: orleans

According to the Microsoft doc [Grain Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/grains/grain-identity), I can get a singleton grain instance by using the key `Guid.Empty` on the client.

Will this singleton grain instance be scoped globally, to the cluster, or to the silo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official docs:

> Orleans ensures that when a grain call is made there is an instance of
> that grain available in memory on some server in the cluster to handle
> the request. If the grain is not currently active in the cluster,
> Orleans picks one of the servers to activate the grain on. This is
> called grain placement. Placement is also one way that load is
> balanced: even placement of busy grains helps to even the workload
> across the cluster.

Meaning, you can specify where the Grains are placed when created/called.

You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/grains/grain-placement